# Change orientation of barplot() in R

Tags: r, graph, bar-chart

I am working on making two back-to-back barplots with the traditional graphics package in R; I have found the horiz argument to the barplot() function, but can't figure out how to flip the horizontally-oriented graph horizontally.

As an example,

```
barplot(mtcars$cyl, horiz = T)
```

gives

[image]

but what I want to make is this (with the x-axis correct, of course).

[image]

Is there a way to do this with the traditional graphics package?

Comment: Why would you want either of those?  They're not even readable.

Comment: @RichardScriven I don't want either of these; I want this type of graph.  I used mtcars because it's data everyone has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this...?

```
barplot(-mtcars$cyl, horiz = TRUE, axes=FALSE)
axis(1, at=-0:-8, labels=0:8)
```

[image]

Comment: YUP.  Much appreciated!